# How can we keep the iOS and Android projects isolated to their own repos, but maintain a React-native repo?

Tags: react-native

#### Background

We have an existing native app implemented on both iOS and Android that we would like to add a new feature with shared code written in React-Native. From what I’ve researched, React-native requires the iOS and Android projects to be subdirectories of the main React-native directory.

As the development of our iOS and Android application can be at different paces, migrating both repos to a single React-Native repo would not work with our current development flow.

#### Researched

I have seen that this question asks a similar question in one of its many questions, "Also, how to organize the VCS ? Is moving the 4 code bases (iOS, Android, Web and the RN bundle) in a mono-repository a necessary move ?"

[How to migrate a multi-platform app in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847210/how-to-migrate-a-multi-platform-app-in-react-native),

That question remains unanswered. Our question is limited in scope in comparison as we would only like an answer to the management of the repos.

#### Question

How can we keep the iOS and Android projects isolated to their own repos, but maintain a React-native repo with a shared codebase for features that are shared by both platforms?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ultimately, my team decided on using a mono repo to avoid the complexity of manually updating each git submodule in the react-native repo.

That being said, **git submodules** would allow managing the iOS and Android repos separately. However, the drawback to this approach would be that updates made to the Android and iOS repos would have to be pulled into the react-native repo each time the individual repos are updated.